# LINQ lambda: how to combine two tables with no links

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables "Foo" and "Bar". I would like to join them on nothing, i.e. I need it to be a full matrix:

Foo

| letters |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |

Bar

| numbers |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

FooBar

| letters | numbers |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 2 |

How do I achieve it using LINQ lambda magic, i.e. something like

```
var Foobar = Foo.UnionAll(b => Bar...)...?
```

Note both tables are `IEnumerable` anonymous.

Comment: You could use `.Zip( numbers, (x,y) => new object[]{ x, y } );`

Comment: Thanks I tried it but it just makes a table with two rows a/b 1/2 so it joins it but doesn't expand/makes full matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should create needed result:

```cs
var Foobar = Foo.SelectMany(f => Bar, (f, b) => new { Foo = f, Bar = b});
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the query syntax of linq:

```
var Foobar = from f in Foo
             from b in Bar
             select new { f.letters, b.numbers };
```